# Probability that two different subsets sharing exactly two elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Given the set $S$ that is the set of all subsets of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Two different sets  are chosen at random from $S$. What is the probability that 
>   the two subsets share exactly two equal elements?

**My attempt**

I found that the universal set  $\Omega = \dfrac{2^n\left(2^n-1\right)}{2}$

Then I tried to find the number of ways to select two subsets sharing two equal elements:

The number of ways to choose one subset that contains $i, j$ is $2^{n-2}$.

The number of ways to choose another subset that contains $i, j$ and is different from the previous is: $\sum{2^{n-k-1}}$

However, I failed to put those two  together to obtain correct result. I wonder whether there is another approach to this problem or how my method could have been continued.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You speak of *different* sets. Is it forbidden then that the (randomly chosen) sets coincide? I interpret that $P(|A\cap B|=2)$ is to be found. Is that correct?

Comment: @drhab Yes, $A \ne B$ and $|A \cap B|$ is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each element $x$ in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and choosing two subsets $A,B$ of this there are four options with the following caveats.

- $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ (*we desire at least two such $x$*)
- $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$
- $x\notin A$ and $x\in B$ (*we require at least one such $x$ in this or the previous to ensure the two selected sets were different*)
- $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$

Our sample space is then of size $4^n-2^n$, getting this as there are $4$ choices for each of the $n$ elements in the set and applying multiplication principle and subtracting away the selections where the second two cases both had zero elements and the subsets then are equal.  (*Dividing by two is fine if you insist on working with the two subsets as indistinguishable, however I see no reason to enforce that*).

---

Now... let us count the number of ways in which strictly fewer than two elements wound up in the first case.  Well... that would be exactly one element ending in the first case or zero elements ending in the first case.

If exactly one element ended in the first case, pick which it was and then pick how to distribute the rest of the elements, again keeping in mind the restriction on the second and third cases.  This gives $n(3^{n-1}-1^{n-1})$

Finally, with no elements ending in the first case, that gives $3^n-1^n$

---

Putting this all together, our final desired probability that our two subsets share at least two equal elements is:

$$1-\frac{n(3^{n-1}-1)+(3^n-1)}{4^n-2^n}$$

---

In the case of desiring exactly two equal elements, simply pick which two elements are used in the first case, then with the remaining elements avoid having sent them all to the fourth case.

This gives probability:

$$\frac{\binom{n}{2}(3^{n-2}-1)}{4^n-2^n}$$

Comment: Sorry for the misleading statement, I forgot to put the word “exactly” two equal element. Could your approach apply to it also?

Comment: why should we avoid case 4? I think a set can contain exactly 2 elements.

Comment: @KM02 where do you think I am avoiding case 4?

Comment: You said this “avoid having sent them all to the fourth case”. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @KM02 By that I mean, avoid having the sets be equal.  Avoid having avoided both of the second and third case.  Avoid having sent none of the elements to either of the second or third cases.

Comment: oh, yes. Thank you, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: to pick two different subsets with exactly two common elements

1. Pick the two common elements in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways
2. The remaining $n-2$ elements either go to the first subset, to second subset, or neither. $3^{n-2}-1$ ways. (minus 1 because we do not want all remaining $n-2$ elements not going to either first or second subset.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable hint. The final probability is $\dfrac{n(n-1)3^n}{4^n-2^n}$ right? (I don’t think that we need to subtract 1 since a set can contains exactly 2 elements)

Comment: @KM02 we need to subtract 1 because we do not want both subset to contain only the common elements. JMoravitz’s answer is correct

Comment: @ Rezha Adrian Tanuharja Why is that? I think both subset contain only the common elements is normal.

Comment: @KM02 remember you want 2 different subsets

Comment: Oh, thanks, I forgot that